# Second-order nonlinear ODE involving cosine of the unknown function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, closed-form, heat-equation

**Question**

> I am interested in solving for $u : S^1 \to S^1$ given the following ODE, where $v : S^1 \to S^1$ is a given continuous function:
>
> $$u'' = -A\cos(u-v) \tag{$\dagger$}$$
>
> Is there any hope of an analytic solution? Can anything be said about the behavior of the solution as $A$ varies? If it helps, I have $\int_{S^1} \cos[v(\theta)]\ d\theta = \int_{S^1} \sin[v(\theta)]\ d\theta = 0$.

**Background**

I've been interested in crystalline and anisotropic mean curvature flows, along the line of the work of Novaga and Chambolle, e.g. https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/cpa.21668

My actual problem is more involved and three-dimensional, but to build intuition I've been trying to think about the following two-dimensional simplification.

Consider a curve $\gamma:S^1 \to \mathbb{R}^2$, which for simplicity we can take to be arclength-parameterized with arc length $2\pi$. Let us write $\gamma'(\theta) = [\cos(v[\theta]), \sin(v[\theta])]$. I want to study sections of the bundle of directors $\hat{m}(\theta) \in S^1$ along the curve: I want these directors to approximate the orientation of the curve normal, while also behaving more smoothly near regions of sharp curvature. Let $\hat{n}(\theta) = [-\sin(v[\theta]), \cos(v[\theta])]$ denote the curve normal at $\theta$; I would like to look at minimizers of the functional
$$E(\hat m) = \int_{S^1} \left(\frac{1}{2}\left\|\hat{m}'(\theta)\right\|^2 + \frac{A}{2} \left\|\hat m(\theta) - \hat n(\theta)\right\|^2\right)\,ds$$
where the real constant $A$ controls the relative importance of smoothness vs adapting to the curve normal.

Applying the calculus of variations, we have that an extremizer $\hat{m}^*(\theta) = [\cos u^*(\theta), \sin u^*(\theta)]$ of $E$ satisfies the ODE
$(u^*)''(\theta) = -A\cos[u^*(\theta) - v(\theta)]$, where $v: S^1\to S^1$ is prescribed by the choice of $\gamma$. And we know that $\int_{S^1} \cos[v(\theta)]\ d\theta = \int_{S^1} \sin[v(\theta)]\ d\theta = 0$, since the curve $\gamma$ is closed. Hence my question.

My eventual goal is to take variations of $E(\hat{m}^*)$ with respect to $\gamma$ to flow the curve, so an analytic solution to the ODE ($\dagger$) would be very helpful.

Some trivial observations: $E(\hat{m}^*)$ is bounded above by on the one hand $A\pi$, and on the other hand, $\int_{S^1} \kappa(\theta)^2\,ds$ (where $\kappa(\theta)$ is the curvature at $\theta$), for a constant director field, and $\hat m = \hat n$, respectively.

Comment: For $v=0$, it's essentially the nonlinear pendulum equation, which has an explicit solution in terms of Jacobi elliptic functions. Looks difficult for arbitrary $v$.

Comment: Close voter: this problem arises from research on certain geometric flows. I'm not sure what additional context you want: I can write a whole derivation that ends at this ODE, but it's irrelevant to my actual question (can it be solved? What does the one-parameter family of solutions look like in $A$)?

Comment: @user7530 I admit I was one of the close voters. Let me explain. What you just said is the context we need on MSE (otherwise this just looks like someone who pasted a problem without motivation). I appreciate that you are doing this for research, and I think that a better site that suits these types of questions would be [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net).

Comment: @TheSimpliFire thanks—-I’m always self conscious about posts to MO, as although this equation arose in the course of my research, it’s surely not a research-level question in ODEs. I expected an expert to tell me “you’re an idiot, this is the textbook XXX-YYY Equation, it’s trivial if you apply the ZZZ integral transform.”

Comment: I agree with TheSimpliFire that your question lacks context. You do not need to write a derivation that ends at the ODE in question, but you should at least state the original problem from which it arose (while leaving out the derivation that you are not interested in). Also, you should have included the information in [your comment here](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/6036296). Although you don't think it helps, someone might know something. So I suggest you edit your question to include such context that is relevant.

Comment: @user21820 I've added the information from the comment. As for the context, I'm sorry but I respectfully but strongly disagree. I may at some point write up the line of questions (totally unrelated to ODEs) that leads to this ODE, but a) I just looked at the ten "Related" questions in the sidebar, and *none* have significantly more context than a polite request for help solving an ODE, and b) if people think the question is too trivial or recognize it as a standard textbook ODE, I don't mind researching on my own if even one voter had told me the ODE name, or other hint where to look.

Comment: @user7530: Please read the [how-to-ask page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Just because there are other examples of questions with no context does not imply that they satisfy the site guidelines. And you are misunderstanding me; I didn't say you need to do a write-up or anything of that sort, just merely should state the problem. One line. Can it be so hard? Anyway thanks for editing your question.

Comment: @user21820 We've been around here nearly the same length of time, and I'm well aware of the drama over homework questions. I suppose I'm taken aback as I've never yet been on the receiving end of the negativity. In any case I've added more background. I fear this version of the question will receive more tumbleweeds than the original more direct formulation, but maybe I'm wrong...

Comment: Okay I see you have added a great deal more than I expected. Thank you very much. I will edit to make your key question more prominent, but feel free to alter or roll back if you don't like my edit.

Comment: I have now retracted my vote.

Comment: Speaking about original equation $u'' = - A \cos{(u - v(x))}$, you are always interested only in its periodic solutions, right? Also, does that equation makes sense to your problem when $A = 0$?

Comment: Yes, periodic solutions. $A=0$ gives trivial constant solutions, so mostly I'm interested in nonzero $A$.

Comment: I think I found quite interesting angle to your question. If it is allowed to introduce new variable $\gamma = u - v(t)$ (the only obstruction could be the smoothness of $v(t)$), then your equation transforms to $\gamma'' = - A \cos \gamma - v''(t) = - A \cos \gamma + f(t) $. As I've understood, you are interested in very large, but still finite values of $A$, right? In that case we can introduce new time $\tau = \frac{t}{\sqrt{A}}$ and transform equation into $\gamma'' = - \cos \gamma + \frac{f(\tau)}{A}$. This is basically a weakly periodically forced mathematical pendulum then.

Comment: In principle, more can be said about periodic solutions of weakly forced mathematical pendulum since it is classical and quite well-researched topic. But I still don't know what smoothness you expect from function $v(x)$ and is it valid to make this transformation in your case.

Answer (score 0):

For arbitrary $v$?  No, no hope.  For certain specific $v$, yes. 
In fact, let $U(\theta)$ be any twice-differentiable function with $|U''/A|< 1$
and take $v(\theta) = U(\theta) + \arccos(U''/A)$, and $U(\theta)$ will be a solution.

Comment: Yes, $v$ is arbitrary unfortunately. (I do know that $\int_{S^1} \cos[v(\theta)] = 0$ but I don't think that helps much.)